# SVN server respond to http range request with full file content, not with range part only

Tags: apache, http, svn

I want to download from SVN server only part of some large file. SVN server is behind Apache HTTP server, so I create HTTP range request. Then got full file content but not requested range part. Server respond with code 200 not 206, so it not supported range requests. How to enable range requests for SVN server?

1. Is it possible to get only range part from SVN?
2. What should I change in SVN server config?
3. May be in Apache server config?

Thanks in advance.

Session log:
request with: `Range: bytes=0-199`
response with: `Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 678852`

```
$ curl -v -r 0-199 -u l_chayka:***** https://svn2.*******.net/svn/****/tech_research/dvpls/meta.dvpk > meta.dvpk
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 10.128.40.150...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to svn2.*******.net (10.128.40.150) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/msys64/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [93 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2580 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=CY; L=*****; O=***** Group Limited; CN=*.******.net
*  start date: Jun  2 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 14 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "svn2.******.net" matched cert's "*.******.net"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'l_chayka'
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /svn/****/tech_research/dvpls/meta.dvpk HTTP/1.1
> Host: svn2.******.net
> Authorization: Basic bF9aGF5a2Rgd5E6VzI0MTkwODZnMTk4NDE=
> Range: bytes=0-199
> User-Agent: curl/7.62.0
> Accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 05 Nov 2018 09:50:00 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;
< Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Nov 2018 12:29:28 GMT
< ETag: "617837//tech_research/dvpls/meta.dvpk"
< Cache-Control: max-age=604800
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 678852
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<
{ [5 bytes data]
100  662k  100  662k    0     0  10.2M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10.2M
* Connection #0 to host svn2.******.net left intact
```